# Where's this in Lillooet BC?

Tags: identify-this, british-columbia

[image: lake picture]

[Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivL-0fwTylMnrJNwKKX42yfhlF2cNRVXb4TPJOJMmhMp7Lz2VXuyjqt1LSRPhAaxFw-oxJ0gHtnI6zZ6B3lnNe9R4NKlkfCGS6cwPvhkVDigTKs8ySgFitQOqd_197eNkknC92VkMb6K1lSvT_1-19aDNuzrk_1Qf7Lem5kBl-GTUVs8Oya4E6SzaUAisPShVeuwfSL1jO6v8sZh2mCJxizd87EPm8LN-ROCN1U1118HhQNMoeljm-MxJqz_1ZSpTCvk5PRv7iIo9oYHjqi3dsAUzTuW0QUwYbZ7V2QG8Vg1ukowBo5_1f_1jWaywIVdYApLDR_1Bkja0W&hl=en-CA) furnished nothing.

1. Where was this photo taken from ?
2. Can I access by private sedan where this girl is standing? Any hiking required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a geotagged picture from the same point of view on [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/40853718@N06/42243315764).

It is a panorama over Seton lake near the town you mention, Lillooet, in British Columbia, Canada.

[image: map of point of view over Seton lake, BC, Canada]

While there is no trail mapped to get to the point of view ([on OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/50.66135/-121.98888)), it is located close to Highway 99 between Pemberton and Lillooet. There is a pull off in the previous turn (accessible in the southbound direction) with enough space to park a few cars or trailers. From there you can cross the road and a small trail starts in the bush. Follow it for a few hundred metres among trees and dirt to a first view point. The picture you link is taken from a second view point located a little further and higher. With sport shoes and the will to climb in the bush, you can get to that point of view.
You can also find this lookout mentioned on some blogs like [this one](https://www.theoutbound.com/canada/hiking/hike-to-a-hidden-viewpoint-of-seton-lake-british-columbia).

[UPDATED] after a visit there. Note that in Covid times (as of Summer 2020), Lillooet prefers people not to stop in the town, plan ahead and get enough fuel and food so you don't need to stop there.

Answer (score 3):

That bend in the road is pretty apparent on a map.  It appears to be Highway 99 about 5 km west of Lillooet.

https://goo.gl/maps/J8AgaCbRJmZuaJHx5

Highway 99 is on Street View, and from the part of the road closest to the river, you can see the mountain on the other side with the distinctive slide.

https://goo.gl/maps/xixjgxVaHms43jjS7

You can drive on Highway 99, of course, and you can see there's also a dirt road on the south side of the ridge, but either way you'd have to hike up to the top of the ridge.